# Calculating Checksum for ICMPv6 Packet

Tags: ipv6, packet-analysis, checksum, icmpv6

I have a packet that has a checksum of 0xffff, and a calculated checksum of 0x0000. I know in UDP, a checksum of 0x0000 is not allowed, and is instead replaced with 0xffff, thus the packet should be validated.

On the other hand, I had a packet with a checksum of 0x0000, and a calculated checksum of 0x0000, in this case, do we still replace it with 0xffff? That would make it invalid packet (incorrect checksum match), but I believe that it is valid (correct checksum match). Are there any rules for such values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With UDP, the checksum is optional, but it's mandatory for ICMP.

Accordingly, you do *not* replace a calculated `0x0000` with `0xffff`.

For reference, check [RFC 4443 2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4443#section-2.3):

> ### 2.3. Message Checksum Calculation
>
> The checksum is the 16-bit one's complement of the one's complement
> sum of the entire ICMPv6 message, starting with the ICMPv6 message
> type field, and prepended with a "pseudo-header" of IPv6 header
> fields, as specified in [IPv6, Section 8.1].  The Next Header value
> used in the pseudo-header is 58.  (The inclusion of a pseudo-header
> in the ICMPv6 checksum is a change from IPv4; see [IPv6] for the
> rationale for this change.)
>
> For computing the checksum, the checksum field is first set to
> zero.

Answer (score 1):

Using the UDP checksum is *optional* for IPv4 (required for IPv6). If the checksum is not used, the checksum is set to all-zeroes. If the checksum is used, and the *computed* checksum is all-zeroes, the checksum is set to all-ones.